Function of JFET in classic transistor feedback regulator power supply
Attached is a schematic of the power supply, of a stereo audio amplifier.  The regulated section seems straightforward enough. Looking at the positive section, Q903, Q905, Q907 and ZD901 seem to be a classic feedback regulator.  My question is, what is the function of JFET Q901?  Thank you in advance.

Photo is from a publicly available service manual, product is about about 40 years old

ELP - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in the [tour] & [help])

Note that "from a publicly available service manual" is not sufficient information to comply with the site rule. You need to say what publicly available service manual--at least say what piece of equipment it's for.


My question is, what is the function of JFET Q901?

Operationally, Q901 is wired as a constant current source. It's not perfect of course but "near enough" for the application in the question. For this particular device (Toshiba's 2SK246), when the gate is connected to source you get this characteristic: -

I've added a red box indicating the characteristic for VGS equaling zero. Basically it base biases Q905 with 5 mA. That current remains at pretty-much 5 mA from a drain-source voltage of below 2 volts to nearly 60 volts.
